# Should I use single quotation mark or double to describe jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to Use Double or Single Quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

I'm confusing what I should use in jQuery.
Some use single some use double quotation mark.
For example

```
$('.class1').removeClass('class1')
$(".class1").removeClass("class1")
```

Also, alert as well

```
alert("aa");
alert('aa');
```

which one is correct?

Comment: you must see:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149192/difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149192/difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a matter of preference than correctness.  See this question for more details: [When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)