# Are there differences between ' and "

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to Use Double or Single Quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)
>   [Difference between single quotes and double quotes in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149192/difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-javascript)

I searched this website and google (in that exact order...) looking for:

Are there any differences between `'` and `"` regarding to `strings` in `Javascript`\ `JQuery`?

Didn't find a thing...

Comment: You're better then **google**!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you pair them properly there is no difference.

Comment: There's quite an important difference: Within a double-quote-delimited string literal (`"foo"`), you can't use a double quote (`"`) without escaping it (`\"`); within a single-quote-delimited string literal, you can. Similarly, within a single-quote-delimited string literal (`'foo'`), you can't use a single quote (`'`) without escaping it (`\'`); within a double-quote-delimited string literal you can. There's no difference in the *resulting strings*, but there's a big difference in the string literals.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no difference at all. It's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Can be used interchangeably in terms of jquery selectors. Once one is chosen for enclosing selector string, then inner quotes will use the "other one", or perhaps be escaped.

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: A little out of time, but it may help another person. Example:
`var string1 = 'Einstein said: "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."';
var string2 = "Einstein said: \"A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new.\"";`. If you output both variables, the resulting string is exactly the same