# Double quotes vs single quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax, semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to Use Double or Single Quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)
>   [Are there differences between ' and "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974026/are-there-differences-between-and)

I am wondering if there is a difference between using single quotes vs double quotes in JavaScript (JQuery selectors etc.).

Both seem to work just fine, so is there a difference?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The difference is that you don't need to escape single quotes in double quotes, or double quotes in single quotes. That is the only difference, if you do not count the fact that you must hold the Shift key to type `"`.

Comment: On German keyboards, you have to use the Shift key for both.

Comment: Gumbo This is also true for a french keyboard configuration.

Comment: On French keyboards, you have to use the Shift key for none :)

Comment: I wish SO had the option to favorite answers in addition to questions...

Answer (score 24):

It doesn't matter unless you're trying to write JSON, in which case you must use double quotes for object literals.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?  Maybe with some examples?

Comment: @JeffAxelrod: the text `{'abc': 123}` is an example of invalid JSON. JSON refuses to delimit text like that with single quotes. (It is technically not valid JavaScript by itself, you would have to write `const x = {'abc': 123}` to make it valid JS. If you don't do that the leading `{` is parsed as a beginning of a code block.) the text `{"abc": 123}` is a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 12):

There is **no** special difference between single and double quotes (like it is in PHP).

The only actual difference is that you can write a double quote `"` in a single-quoted string without escaping it, and vice versa.

So, if you are going to output some HTML in your JavaScript, like this:

```
<div id = "my_div"></div>
```

single quotes are more useful :-)

Comment: And if you have an HTML output like `<div id = 'my_div'></div>`, double quotes are more useful.

Comment: Sure :-) I used the example because double quotes are more common. But yes, the point is - use whatever quotes are not present in the string.

Comment: I agree with Imp but whatever quote style you use, the golden rule is to be consistent.

Comment: In php, variables within double quoted literals are evaluated. They aren't within single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

They work the same, but they must match.  You cannot start a string with a single and end with a double, or the opposite.  Other than that, they are interchangeable.