# how to display weather icons openweather api in react

Tags: reactjs

im trying to display weather icons from open weather map api , but am not entirely sure how to do it , here is the documentation https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions .. im passing inthe image url just like its written in the docs but im just getting a broken image instead ,can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong? thanks

App,js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    temperature: "",
    city: "",
    country: "",
    pressure: "",
    humidity: "",
    description: "",
    rain:"",
    main:"Drizzle",
    icon: "09d",
    error: ""
  }

  handlenum1Change (evt) {



let temp = (evt.target.value);




}


  getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.city.value;

    const api_call = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
    const data = await api_call.json();

    if (city) {
      this.setState({
        temperature: data.main.temp,
        city: data.name,
        main: data.main,
        data.weather[0].icon,
        rain: data.rain,
        pressure: data.main.pressure,
        humidity: data.main.humidity,
        description: data.weather[0].description,
        error: ""
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        temperature: undefined,
        city: undefined,
        country: undefined,
        humidity: undefined,
        description: undefined,
        pressure:undefined,
        rain : undefined,
        error: "Please enter the values."
      });
    }
  }




  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="main">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-5 title-container">


                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-7 form-container">
                  <form onSubmit={this.getWeather} >

                  <input type="text" name="city" onChange={this.handlenum1Change} placeholder="City..."/>

    <button>Get Weather</button>


    </form>




                  <Weather 
                    temperature={this.state.temperature} 
                    humidity={this.state.humidity}
                    city={this.state.city}
                       pressure={this.state.pressure}
                    description={this.state.description}
                    rain={this.state.rain}
                    icon={this.state.icon}
                    error={this.state.error}
                  />
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

weather.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Weather = props =>
  <div>
    <p>{props.city}</p> 

        <p> humidity {props.humidity }</p> 

        <p> {props.description} </p>
    <p> temperature {props.temperature}</p> 
     <p> atmospheric pressure : {props.pressure}</p> 
 <p> atmospheric pressure : {props.rain}</p> 


 <img className="img-fluid" src={'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${props.icon}.png'}/>
  </div>





export default Weather;
```

Comment: `icon` prop is under `weather` object array. `icon: data.icon` should be `icon: data.weather[0].icon`

Comment: changed it still nothing , but thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe `props.icon` is returning "09d" instead of just 09d. Try calling `src={'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/$' + {props.icon} + '.png'}`

Comment: <img className="img-fluid"   src={'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/$' + '{props.icon}'  + '.png'}/>  returns an error in the console   :                                                                        
        Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Your image src is wrong too.  you nee to use back-ticks not single quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067319/back-tick-vs-single-quote-in-js

Comment: Take out the `$`. This link works: http://openweathermap.org/img/w/09d.png

Answer (score 0):

If you call the image like this `<img className="img-fluid" src="openweathermap.org/img/w/" + {props.icon} + ".png"/>` and you still see an error, that probably means you're trying to view the image before `props.icon` is available--before the api call returns the data.

Add something like `loading: true` to your state. Then add something like this to `getWeather`:

```
fetch("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${this.state.city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric")
.then(data => data.json())
.then(data => this.setState({ loading: false }));
```

(You'll also want to use data in the above line to set all of the appropriate values like you're already doing.)

Update `handlenum1Change` to actually grab the value of the city that's entered:

`this.setState({ city: evt.target.value });`

Then wrap the Weather component:

`{ this.state.loading ? '' : <Weather/> }`

With the above line nothing should display until the data is returned from fetch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the URL, instead of just the icon value. In this case, you can use:

[http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${this.state.icon}.png](http://openweathermap.org/img/w/$%7Bthis.state.icon%7D.png)

The final code should be:

```
<img src = {'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${this.state.icon}.png'}/>
```