# Tracking of a button click in jquery

Tags: jquery

Following is the html code for a button.I need to track this button click.

```
<div class="abc">
    <a class="btn" data-wap="{"linktype":"xyz"}" href="#content">
</div>
```

Comment: You will want to change your `.btn` HTML to: `<a class="btn" data-wap='{"linktype":"xyz"}' href="#content">`. The nested double quotes could cause potential issues.

Comment: You can use this question(of mine) and the duplicated questions as reference for the quotes problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/8974026/601179

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a.btn').click(function(){
    //here
});
```

Note:

- `<a>` isn't a button.
- If you want to cancel the default behavior and the bubbling `return false` from the callback.
- Fix the quotes in the `data-wap`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

You also need to close the anchor tag using `</a>`. As suggested by @MichaelWright, you also need to adjust the quotes of your `data-wap`

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event to click like this:

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    // code here
});
```

Also your quotes are incorrect which could cause issues for you, use single quotes within the double quotes so it doesn't break them.

```
<a class="btn" data-wap="{'linktype':'xyz'}" href="#content">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$('a.btn').click(function(){
    //here
}) ;
```

Comment: What's the point in duplicate others answers? (including the placeholder value...!)

Comment: actually i did not see that answer when i tried to post.after post only i see them

Answer (score 0):

try this

**HTML**

```
 <div class="abc">
    <a class="btn" data-wap="{'linktype':'xyz'}" href="#content"></a>
 </div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('a.btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("clicked");
});
```