# valid() function not working in jquery form validation MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am creating a simple mvc3 application.

the VIew is

```
<script>
function Submitform() {
    var form = $('#frmAddStudent');
    if (form) {
        if (form.valid()) {
            $(form).submit();
        }
    }
}
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddStudent", "Student", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { id = "frmAddStudent" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StudentName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model => model.DOB)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB)
    </div>
<p>
   <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn" onclick="return Submitform()" />
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="close btn" onclick="closeDialog()" />
    </p>
}
```

now the Problem is when i click on Submit button javascript function calls and it doesn't recognize "form.valid()" function.

it displays 
***form.valid()  TypeError: form.valid is not a function***

so, whats the Problem in this .

Comment: What all JS files you have included in your view? Can you post that part of code?

Comment: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var form = $( "#frmAddStudent" );
form.validate();

function Submitform() {
    if (form.valid()) {
            $(form).submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here the only change is double quote from single quote, which is not going to help. Both are same, see [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149192/difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: Please look carefull `form.validate();` is the real change, you need to initialize validator before using it.

Comment: same error is coming 
form.validate()
 
TypeError: form.validate is not a function

Comment: Can you run $( "#frmAddStudent" ) in your browser's javascript console and verify that only one object is returned?