# Is it a better idea to use "" or '' to encapsulate a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, string

I have googled on this issue. There seems to be no difference between using "" or '' to encapsulate a string. It is hard to decide. Is it correct to say it is a better idea to use "" because it is compulsory in json to use ""?

Comment: [Difference between single quotes and double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149192/difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-javascript) or [When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

As you might know javascript is a loosely typed language, which means there is no real difference between the two cases, some programmers who has a c++, c#, java background experience still using single quotes for one letter and double quotes for strings, actually it is back to you which one you prefer to use.

Comment: What does loose/weak typing have to do with the quotes you use to encapsulate a string?

Comment: The parser is not strict to make developer you one type meaning you have a choice where is some compiled languages you don't have that choice.