# How can i clean the spaces and new lines?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following output :

> (**a lot of new lines here**)
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy   text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry.
>
> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
>
> text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took
>
> a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
>
> (**a lot of new lines here**)
>
> It has survived not only five centuries,
>
> but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
>
> remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
>
> in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem
>   Ipsum passages,

To clean this up i am using a lot of regex

```
var body = contentDiv.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ').replace(/([^\r\n][^\n])(?:\r?\n)([^\r\n][^\n])/g,"$1$2");
$('eBody').value = body.replace(/\n{3,}/g, '\n').replace(/^\s\s*/, '');
```

Where `contentDiv` is the text above and is returned by a `getElementsByTagName`.

```
var contentDiv = element.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].textContent;
```

It is just that the div has a lot of formatting (  ...), that when i call the `textContent` function, I do get the text with spaces and extra new lines, normally it should look like:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
>
> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
>   remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089925/at-witts-end-javascript-wont-replace-n , maybe this helps ?

Comment: Is your regex not working, or you're just looking for an alternative?

Comment: yes I am just looking for an alternative, cuz i didnt like the replace replace there :/

Comment: You could combine the space and newline removal with something like: `.replace(/\s*(\r?\n){2,}\s*/g,"$1$1");` if that's what you're after?

Comment: @MNS All singing, all dancing version added as an answer :) - longer, than my commented one, but does more

Comment: xD indeed, Awesome thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single regex replace for removing leading and trailing whitespaces, as well as limiting the amount of consecutive newlines:

```
str = str.replace(/(\s*((\r?\n){2,})\s*|\s*((\r?\n){1,2})\s*)/g,"$2$4");
```

Turns:

```
asdfasdf 


asdfafd
 sdf  
d
d sa  






 sadfdsaf
```

Into:

```
asdfasdf

asdfafd
sdf
d
d sa

sadfdsaf
```

**Just fix 3+ multiple newlines**

```
.replace(/(\r?\n){3,}/g,"$1$1");
```

**Just fix leading and trailing whitespaces**

```
.replace(/^ *| *$/gm,'');
```

**Update: first expression didn't clear spaces at beginning and end of string**

Now does everything!

```
.replace(/^\s*|\s*$|(\s*((\r?\n){2,})\s*|\s*((\r?\n){1,2})\s*)/g,"$2$4");
```

Comment: @MNS No worries - latest update (bottom of answer) also cleans spaces at beginning and end of string (first one only does spaces either side of newlines)

Answer (score 0):

Also this one works Great :)

```
s/^\s*(?:(\r?\n)(?:[\s^\r\n]+)(.+?))$/\1\2/gm
```